# Dividing first n integers into subsets

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was wondering when first $n$ integers can be divided into 2 subsets with equal sum.
It is obviously possible in case of even numbers
Eg  $n =4$
$$\{1,2,3,4 \} \Rightarrow \{1,4\}, \{2,3\}$$
It is not possible for $n$ of the form $4k+1$ as sum to $n$ integers is odd.
But it is possible for $n$ of the form $4k-1$ (I think)
Eg  $n =7$ 
$$\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\} \Rightarrow \{1,3,4,6\}, \{2,5,7\}$$
Can someone prove this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: “It is obviously possible in case of even numbers” — No. The simplest counterexample, $n=2$, already appears in the answer, but actually it is false for any even number of the form $n=4k+2$, as the sum of all numbers then is $(4k+2)(4k+3)/2 = (2k+1)(4k+3)$ and thus odd.

Answer (score 2):

The natural approach is to use induction.  It's false for $n=1$ or $n=2$, but it works for $n=3$.  So the proposition as stated so broadly is just plain false.

So let's consider your narrower claim that it's true for $n = 3~(mod~4)$.  It's certainly true for $n=3$.  Assume it's true for $k = 3~(mod~ 4)$.   Thus you have partitioned all these integers $\{1, ..., k\}$into two subsets $A$ and $B$ the sums of whose elements are equal.  Then when you add four more integers in sequence, you can take the first and fourth new integers and append them to $A$, and you can take the second and third new integers and append them to $B$.  Then their sums are still equal.

Comment: So it is possible exactly if the sum of the numbers is even.

Comment: When $n = 3$, it works for $A=\{1,2\}$ and $B=\{3\}$.  The sums of the elements of these sets is not even.

Comment: I meant the sum of *all* numbers. $1+2+3=6$ which is quite obviously even. It is quite obvious that if that sum is not even, there's no way to divide the set into two subsets with equal sum; the not so obvious part is that the sum being even is already a sufficient condition.

Comment: The sum of the first n integers is n(n+1)/2.  You’re right.  The proposition is also true for k = 0 (mod 4).  The same proof works, with the initial case of n=4.  When So it’s necessary and sufficient that the sum be even.